# Total count for each month within period

Tags: postgresql

Given this scenario , I have the following employment records

```
id | user_id   |  Month          | Active
1  | 1         |  June 2014      | true
2  | 1         |  September 2014 | false
3  | 2         |  June 2014      | true
```

How can i make a query to return the total active users for each month, the return data should be:

```
active_count | month
2            | June 2014
2            | July 2014
2            | August 2014
1            | September 2014
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: How does `August 2014` get into the result? It's not in your sample data.

Comment: Yes, what i want is to return the total active users from June -> September, therefor I'm gonna have 2 active in June/July/August, but only 1 in September since 1 employee is inactive in September

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a conditional aggregate:

```
SELECT count(case when active then 1 end) as active_count,
       month
FROM employment 
GROUP BY month;
```

With Postgres 9.4 this can be written a bit more concise using the `filter()` operator:

```
SELECT count(*) filter (where active) as active_count,
       month
FROM employment 
GROUP BY month;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sql query try to this

```
SELECT  
    count(id) active_count,
    month
FROM
    employment 
GROUP BY
    month;
```